# Need help, when I run a "Execute Package Task" to call a child Package, the child package works, but the parent Package gets a error message

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ssis-2012

> Error: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_PackageTaskLog_PackageLog". The conflict occurred in database
>   "SSIS_PDS", table "dbo.PackageLog", column 'PackageLogID'.

Comment: Hi Bruno, I'd suggest providing a little more context about the problem you're trying to resolve.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

and welcome.

I'm guessing that your package is trying to insert the PackageLog table with an identifier that's derived from the PackageTaskLog table, however the PackageTaskLog table doesn't have that value.

Hope this helps.